# PyCharm debug subprocess/Popen got the error message

Tags: python, ansible, pycharm

I use dynamic script to fetch host info which providing by **ansible** framework.

```
path = '/Volumes/Work@SSD/code/python/icode_devop_be/app/libs/ansible/sources/redis_set_sources.py'
host = 'WIN-2OLQLBCH8FO'
cmd = [path, "--host", host]
try:
    sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
except OSError as e:
    raise AnsibleError("problem running %s (%s)" % (' '.join(cmd), e))
(out, err) = sp.communicate()
```

When I debug the code in **Pycharm**, I got the error message:

```
b'usage: redis_set_sources.py [-h] (--list | --host HOST)\nredis_set_sources.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --port 57112 --client 127.0.0.1 --multiproc --file WIN-2OLQLBCH8FO\n'
```

But I run the command in the terminal got the correct message:

Command:

```
app/libs/ansible/sources/redis_set_sources.py --host 'WIN-2OLQLBCH8FO'
```

Normal Message:

```
{"hostname": "WIN-2OLQLBCH8FO", "port": 5985, "ansible_host": "192.168.0.254", "ansible_user": "administrator", "ansible_ssh_password": "All4Icode", "connection": "winrm", "private_key": null, "transport": "ntlm"}
```

Comment: Are you just givin --host as argument? What is that: --port 57112 --client 127.0.0.1 --multiproc --file? Make sure that every space you would have on commandline becomes an element of your cmd list. Cmd = [command, "--a1", d, "--a2", e]

Comment: They don’t look like the same command though.

Comment: Yes, I just givin the --host parameter. These parameters '--port 57112 --client 127.0.0.1 --multiproc --file' were added by the pycharm debugger @user2853437

Answer (score 0):

Definitly you pass unexpected parameters to your command, as the error message would also indicate in the terminal if you pass them:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: --port 57112 --client 127.0.0.1 --multiproc --file
```

I think the solution to your problem is described in this article:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7464?_ga=2.7923002.94425001.1581367237-1197479344.1576355856

Basically it advices to:

1. Close PyCharm
2. Edit the .idea/workspace.xml file and change the line from :

< option name="MULTIPROCESS" value="true" />

to

```
<option name="MULTIPROCESS" value="false" />
```

3. Restart pycharm
4. Run the script in Debug and it works again.

I'm not sure if it is your solution, but the issue pattern looks the same.